# How do I resize Layout/View size manually or dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout

I have implemented a dragable view its working fine with the reference of this link.

http://blahti.wordpress.com/2011/01/17/moving-views-part-2/

But, Now I have a problem with this view I needs to resize this view manually at run time.

Please suggest me how do I implement this task. Thank You

Answer (score 1):

```
View view = ... some view (ImageView, View etc etc)
view.getLayoutParams().height = newHeight;
view.getLayoutParams().width = newWidth;
```

Comment: Thank's for reply Carnal but I know this method but this not worked for my query. My query is I created a view in my app and I want to drag and resize this view on touch event.

Comment: I see, you will need to somehow handle multiple touch events, and use this method I wrote.

Comment: Ok Thnk's, I will try... If you have any idea how do I implement handle view size on run time please suggest me. and I am also doing for same.

Comment: You want to resize the view with your fingers, or just when dragging around it should resize by itself?

Comment: I want to resize the view by finger touch. Actually I also try to implement this view using Canvas but its not working properly... where ever i touched on screen view reduce our size according my touch place